# Component does not get called in mapping ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, iteration, components

The following is my piece of code where the inside component i.e. `MultiSelectAssetDropdown` does not get rendered. The `console.log('comes here')` doesn't come up, which clearly means that the loop isn't executing. However the prior `console.log` prints fine.. so I know this component is rendered. Also the component render after the loop executes perfectly fine.

```
<ul className="collapsible multiDropdownTag">
  { console.log('field',this.state.configDefaultVal)}
  { configDefaultVal.map(function (field) {
    console.log('comes here');
    return (
      <MultiSelectAssetDropdown placeholder="" icon=""
        label={field.defaultValues.DisplayName}
        value={field.selectedValues}
        disabled={this.state.disabledVal}
        selectedValues={field.selectedValues}
        className="multiselect"
        defaultValues={field.defaultValues.values}
        fieldValue="field1" id="field1"/>
    )}, this)
  }
  <MultiSelectAssetDropdown placeholder="" icon=""
    label="Sites"
    value={abc}
    siteId={this.state.details.siteId}
    disabled={this.state.disabledVal}
    selectedValues={abc}
    defaultValues={abc}
    fieldValue="sites" id="sites"/>
</ul>
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction here? 
The array looks like : `[field1: Array(0), field0: Array(0)]`
However when i do `.length` it gives 0

```
const finalFieldsArray = [];
                _.forEach(configVal,function(selField,key){
                    _.forEach(configDefaultVal,function(defField,keys){
                        if(key == keys){
                            finalFieldsArray[keys]=[];
                            finalFieldsArray[keys]['selectedValues'] = selField;
                            finalFieldsArray[keys]['defaultValues'] = defField;
                        }
                    })
                })
```

This finalFieldsArray is later set in state as configDefaultVal.

Comment: well... if the map function doesn't run could it be that there's nothing in the array?

Comment: @JohnRuddell apologies I will post the array as well as I get it in the console log

Comment: why dont you just post what it is? in the code. instead of these pointless console.logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The array looks like : [field1: Array(0), field0: Array(0)]

Why?

```
const array = [];
array['field1'] = [];
array['field0'] = [];
console.log(array) // => [field1: Array(0), field0: Array(0)]
```

This i not a array, correct array like:

```
const array = [];
array.put([]);
array.put([]);
console.log(array) // => [Array(0), Array(0)]
```

Update your `finalFieldsArray` to make `map` work:

```
const finalFieldsArray = [];
_.forEach(configVal, function(selField,key){
    _.forEach(configDefaultVal, function(defField, keys) {
        if(key == keys) {
            finalFieldsArray.push({
                key: key,
                value: {
                    selectedValues: selField,
                    defaultValues: defField
                }
            });
         }
     })
 })
```

Comment: I have edited my question to give an idea as to how I am making this array/object.

Comment: i was updated my aswer, but you should thing about object instead of an array

Comment: This approach works perfectly fine, thanks,btw can you tell me what was the issue with the previous approach?

Comment: JS array using only numeric to index value, so array[2] work but array['key'] not.